# How to automate any application variable directly without GUI with Python?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I need to automate some workflows to control some Mac applications, I have got a way to do this with Pyautogui module,but I don't want to simulate keyboard or mouse actions anymore, I think if I can get the variables under any GUI elements and program with them directly it would be better, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless the application has some kind of api.
For Web GUIs you can use Selenium and directly select the DOM elements.